# Asp net back button of browser causes page not found

Tags: asp.net, browser

In my home page I redirect after some action from the user to another page. Now if the user hits the back button of the browser I would like the previous page to be loaded again. Instead I have a page not found error.
In my home page the code in my page_load event handler is as follows:

```
if (IsPostBack) return;

DataTable dt = db.GetDT("SELECT * FROM Locations");
cbDests.DataSource = dt;

cbDests.DataTextField = "Name";
cbDests.DataValueField = "ID";
cbDests.DataBind();
Calendar1.SelectedDate = DateTime.Now.Date;
```

How do I avoid the browser not finding the page? 
Is it because I am in debug mode?

### Edit

The code to redirect is:

```
Response.Redirect("findflights.aspx");
```

The URL before I redirect is:

```
http://localhost:50156/findflights
```

Comment: what is the url on browser address bar before and after you hit back button?

Comment: http://localhost:50156/findflights

Comment: So you're redirecting from `http://localhost:50156/findflights` to `http://localhost:50156/findflights.aspx`?

Comment: no from http://localhost:50156/findflights to http://localhost:50156/Default
After pressing the backbutton the page default cannot be found, the browser asks to press refresh button in order to reload. When I do that the page is reloaded.

Comment: Hello again, sorry for my wrong answer. Actually when I hit the back button, the url stays at findflights page, it does not find the way to go to Default page. I hope this helps to detect the problem?

Comment: I found out that this problem does not occur on Firefox. It is occurring on Microsoft Edge...